# Valid JSON Array logs Undefined to the console no matter what I do

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm using Jquery to call a php script which then generates an array. I'm using

```
echo json_encode (array ( "key"=>$value, "key"=>$value, "key"=>$value ));
```

As the last line of the PHP document which is generating a valid JSON array. I checked via Firebug. Unfortunately when I try to access one of the values with dot-notation, it's coming up as undefined.

```
$.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        cache       : false,
        url     : "/generateArray.php",
        data        : { data: $(this).attr('id') },
        success: function(data) {
                     console.log(data.key);
        }
```

This is outputting "undefined" to the console, even though when I check the JSON output the array is valid.

I have no idea how to even begin debugging what's wrong with my code. Please help!

Comment: Sounds like you might have a problem with your encoded data.  [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is your friend in this case: it will show you exactly what is being sent.  This is where you begin debugging. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure `data` is being `json decoded` on the Javascript side and isn't just a `String`?

Comment: This is the most likely cause of the problem - set at least one of the following: `dataType='json'` in the ajax call or `header('Content-type: application/json')` in PHP

Comment: Agreed, where is your parse function...  Here is the URL to download the office [JavaScript JSON.org parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Comment: Thanks so much, I added JSON.parse and now it's working perfectly.